# How to parse encoded data from XML to Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I have an XML-file where I have a structure in which some of the data is encoded. When I convert the XML-file into Excel file, the column for the encoded data is presented by the URL.

Is there any way I can parse that data into actual data for anylizing?

Comment: Quite confused question. What does "some of the data is encoded" mean? To put any data in digital form, you need to encode it. Or do you mean it was crypted? Provide a sample of this XML file, this will be much better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "the encoded data is presented by the URL". Can you give more details or maybe show an example?

How do you perform the conversion to an excel file?


Either way, you can import data into excel using a selected encoding (from office 2003 and forward). That may help with your problem.